# Using SELECT INTO in HSQL 2.2 routines

Tags: function, hsqldb, procedures, routines

When I migrate a Oracle Function to HSQLDB I need translate the "Select into" for HSQLDB. The Oracle script may look like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getId()
RETURN NUMBER IS 
       temp_id NUMBER;
...

BEGIN
....    
  SELECT id id INTO temp_id from ( select id form ..... );
```

In HSQLDB 2.0.0, I can do the following:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION getId()
RETURNS BIGINT 
BEGIN ATOMIC 
  DECLARE temp_id BIGINT;
....

  SET temp_id = SELECT id id FROM ....
```

However, it doesn't work in HSQLDB 2.2.9 anymore. The error message is:

> [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -5608, SQL State: 42608]
>   wrong or missing data impact clause in declaration: READS SQL in
>   statement

From the release note of HSQLDB 2.2, it says they already support "select into", but I didn't find the way.

Anyone know how to do it in HSQLDB 2.2.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.2.x series there are more strict data access checks. A routine that reads table data must be declared as such.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getId()
RETURNS BIGINT READS SQL DATA 
BEGIN ATOMIC 
  DECLARE temp_id BIGINT;
....

  SET temp_id = SELECT id id FROM ....
```

More enhancments and fixes have been introduced in recent months. It is better to use the latest snapshot jar (and version 2.3.0 when it is released) instead of 2.2.9.

http://www.hsqldb.org/repos/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/SNAPSHOT/

The snapshot directory is a Maven repository.